# Vintage childrens' fantasy about a boy who bites a dragon claw and can hear the dragon thoughts

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I read it in the sixties and it was about a young boy about ten, who had to go and stay in the English countryside where there were a lot of so-called 'dragon' mounds.  I can't remember anything about the story except he meets a young girl, and he is captured inside a huge cavern and lifted off the ground by a dragon.  He bites the claw and tastes bitter blood, which then enables him to hear the dragon's thoughts.